# xcode warnings and game problems after building for IOS from UNITY 3D

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

So my finished game is working perfectly on android after building it on unity and i tested it and all everything looks perfect. Now after switching platform to ios then building it and importing it to xcode i get slapped with over 1000 warnings. I thought that the issue was with my game so i downloaded the unity mobile place holder project and tested it and it had even more warnings than my game.

[image: warnings from xcode]

see now I do not mind these warnings because the game still builds fine however i lose alot of FPS from the game to the point where it is unplayable. I tried testing it on phone and simulator. The game runs 100+ fps in unity but in XCODE its 1 fps or 2 fps.

another set of warnings that might pop up from time to time.

[image: second set of warnings]

solutions i tired:

-Building then zipping the file incase some files may be lost during the 
 transfer from my windows to my mac machine

-Building for iphone only or ipad only, building for device only or 
 simulator only.

-building the game with .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.6

-I tried almost every solution on the internet but i dont know why the game is so laggy.

I hope you can help me. Thank you

Comment: go and check where that log comes from cause it is not using dealloc so the game will run slower and slower and finally crash...

Comment: how can i do that? @Calleth'Zion'

Comment: on your monodevelop/visual studio solution search in files for: "Allocation of" and find where that log comes from...